# "the other two of which" or "the other two"?

Tags: grammar

Is "the other two of which" in the following sentence correct?

"Neurons may be categorized into four types, two of which are strengthened and rise to dominance, while **the other two of which** are weakened and become negligible."

Or should we omit "of which"? I.e.

"Neurons may be categorized into four types, two of which are strengthened and rise to dominance, while **the other two** are weakened and become negligible."

The former seems more grammatically correct to me, but I'm not so sure.

Comment: I would probably leave off the second "of which" as a matter of style.

Comment: They are both grammatical. (Something either is or isn't—it's not a matter of *more*. For that, you would be talking about something being more or less *idiomatic*.) The difference is one of style and personal choice.